# Eclipse & TomEE: no JPA logging

Tags: eclipse, logging, openjpa, apache-tomee

I am working with Eclipse and TomEE 1.7.1.

If I have a problem with Exception logging of (Open)JPA:
Errors are not logged to console nor to logging file.

For example:

```
entityManager.createQuery("THIS IS NOT SQL");
```

If I run this in my WebApp it won't show anything into console.
BUT: If I set a Breakpoint and execute it manually (via Inspect Cntrl+Shift+I) the Exception is shown in console.

WTF is going on???

---

EDIT:

I have made a test-project with only three files, copied it into Tomee-Webapps-Folder started Tomee directly. Same result: nothing to see in console and no logfile was generated.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="hprex">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>


        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytest"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

<!--             <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Runtime=TRACE, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>                         -->
<!--             <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true"/> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

test.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
<h:commandButton action="#{loginBean.login}"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

LoginBean.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="mytest")
    private EntityManager em;


    public String login() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("This is not SQL");
        query.getResultList();
        return "test";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this path will result in anything being logged by the JPA provider. When OpenJPA can't create that query, it'll throw an exception back to your application.

Comment: You are right. This will throw an ArgumentException which is a RuntimeException.
So I guess, I have to log the RuntimeExceptions, but how? And why is it not logged by default? Currently I ran in that Exception but have no information about it neither in Console nor in Log-Files.
I think, I missunderstood some fundermental concept of Logging/Exceptionhandling in TomEE.

Comment: You should probably catch all PersistenceExceptions and handle appropriately. ie: Log the message, or dump it to SystemOut/Err.

Comment: Is there an easy way to catch all Exceptions generally? Or do I have to wrap a try/catch-block on every query?

Comment: I generally would not expect to encounter exceptions at runtime. Be sure to test your queries and they should be successful in production.

Answer (score 0):

what's your setup/config? By default exceptions are logged. You can check: catalina.out, catalina*.log and localhost*.log dependning the config you have for defaults locations  (if you use log4j, slf4j...that's on your side to ensure it is logged).

Comment: I have made no config, I just use plain Tomee-config. I have added some code to my question.